# Calling method in main method

Tags: java

I want this code to generate a random number between one and five and then, using that number, chose a symbol out of my `arraylist` and print it.  Whenever I try to call the `printSymbol()` method it tells me to change it and the `arraylist` to static.  When I do it gives me two errors on the method call line in my main method and the line where it says that `String y = list.get(x);`  I want to know how to make it so I can call this method and get it to print String y for me.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class study {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printSymbol();
}
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
public void addSymbols(){
    list.add("あ");
    list.add("い");
    list.add("う");
    list.add("え");
    list.add("お");
}
public String printSymbol(){
    int x=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1;
    String y = list.get(x);
    return y;
}

}
```

Comment: You cannot use instance/instance methods inside static context.

Answer (score 3):

You're messing up by mixing static and non-static contexts.

The `printSymbol()` method is part of the class `study`. (Use `Study` instead, that's the proper convention. For more information on these conventions, look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)).

The main method is in a static context. This means that you need to make an object of the class `Study` and then call the printSymbol method on that object.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Study study = new Study(); // create a new object of the class Study
    study.printSymbol();       // call the printSymbol method on this object
}
```

You could also make the `printSymbol()` method and the `ArrayList` static, but that is bad practice in Java, which is an object oriented language.

Answer (score 1):

Your main method is static, which means it can be called without creating an object. Main methods always have to be static, because on startup of the program you don't have an object yet.

The thing about static methods is, you can only access other static members from it unless you create an object you work with.

You have two possible solutions:

Make the other members static, which I wouldn't recommend as you are already using a field, or use an object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    study myObject = new study();
    study.printSymbol();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class study {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   study newStudy = new study();
   newStudy.addSymbols();
   newStudy.printSymbol();
}
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
public void addSymbols(){
   list.add("a");
   list.add("b");
   list.add("c");
   list.add("d");
   list.add("e");
}

public String printSymbol(){
    int x=(int) Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1;
    String y = list.get(x);
    return y;
}
}
```

Your random was also wrong, its needs to be Math.random()*4.
I just replaced your symbols with ASCII for my machine to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Like every one suggested, avoid static method and create an object then call your methods.

And dont forget to add the symbols to the arraylist, you can do it in the constructor or in the main method after creating the object and before calling `printSymbol()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new study().printSymbol();
}
public study() {
    // add symbols to the array list
    addSymbols();
}
```

Or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    study s = new study();
    // add symbols to the array list
    s.addSymbols();
    s.printSymbol();
}
```

Also by [convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) Classnames should start with an upser case letter.

Answer (score 0):

`main` is a static method and from it you may either call static methods, or you have to create an instance of the class and call instance methods of it. Also in your case `list` is an instance variable and thus it can not be accessed from static methods.

I believe the best option for you is to do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    study s = new study();
    s.printSymbol();
}
```

Also please use capital names for classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public `static` String printSymbol(){

 public `static` void addSymbols(){
```

The `main` method is in static context, so all other method its calling needs to be as well.